# Casts in 2D object array in Java

Tags: java, casting, multidimensional-array, polymorphism

I'm working on a checkers game in java. I'm representing my board like this:

```
Object[][] board = new Object[8][8];
```

I want to be able to place a ***Checker*** object or a ***null*** value in the 2D Object Array.

I have a method that assigns ***Checker*** objects to locations in the 2D object array.

My problem is, when I go to write my test for the method:

```
    public void testPopulateCheckers() {
        assertEquals("Red", game.board[0][4].color)
    }
```

The *color* method (which is a method for my ***Checker*** class) does not show up. I've tried casting it as a ***Checker***,but it only lists the ***Object*** methods available.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran It is obvious, `color` is a field.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad : I know it, but it's mentioned as a method in the question!

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran Oh, you are right

Comment: color is a field. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your matrix like this..

```
Object[][] board = new Checker[8][8];

public void testPopulateCheckers() {
    assertEquals("Red", ((Checker) game.board[0][4]).color)
}
```

You need to cast it.

EDIT : method added!

Comment: This wouldn't help, since the type of the variable is still Object[][].

Comment: @Joeri Hendrickx : He tries to cast it, so, placed like that.

Comment: Tried this and Eclipse still only lists the Object methods available for game.board[0][4], not recognizing it as a Checker object.

Comment: @Joeri Hendrickx will you please remove the down vote..? Since your point isn't valid & required.

Comment: With the cast, it could work.  But still, it makes a lot more sense to declare it as `Checker[][]`.  Answer below is better.

Answer (score 5):

```
// This should work
public void testPopulateCheckers() {
    assertEquals("Red", ((Checker) game.board[0][4]).color)
}
```

However, if all you are storing are Checker objects or null, change your declaration to this so you do not have to cast.

```
Checker[][] board = new Checker[8][8];
```

Comment: My hesitation with declaring it as a 2D Checker array is that it doesn't fit the idea that a "board" object "holds" Checker objects, that the spaces certainly are not Checker objects. In my game engine I depend on certain locations of the board being nil (or null, this a a Ruby to Java translation)

Comment: This works for my situation, thanks. I'm still a little uneasy about leaving the concept that the board should be more of a generic container, but your advice, and others who gave similar advice, did fix my current problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Checker to declare your matrix if you expect to call a method like color() on it.

```
Checker[][] board = new Checker[ 8 ][ 8 ];
```

and of course make sure that you initialize all of the 64 Checkers since only the board is initialized by the line above.

Comment: I don't want the possibility of calling Checker methods on "void" spaces or non-occupied spaces. Is there a way to safeguard this?